# Is there a way to monitor email volume from terminal?

Tags: linux, email, redhat-enterprise-linux, monitoring, htop

Is there a way that I can monitor email activity and volume of sending right from terminal?

What I am thinking of is something like htop - but for email activity. My googling has left me empty handed so far, so I figured I'd ask here.

Comment: You probably should include some more information in that case and what actual information you would like to see. A `htop` like view for you MTA would be `htop` as it shows CPU usage etc. for the process. In addition you probably should specify the MTA you're using as there could be a very diverse toolset depending on what MTA you're using.

Comment: Sendmail and postfix should log out sent mail.  You could write a bash script that parses logs and uses regex to look for keywords for sent mail.  Depends on if you need graphical monitoring or simple metrics.